# How to add JS support to the Ruby Mechanize gem?

Tags: javascript, ruby, mechanize

is there a way to add JavaScript support to mechanize so that it will handle simple redirection like `document.location.href=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support that, you'd only need to extract the href parameter ( using a regex maybe ) and then do :

```
mech.get(href_param)
```

As far as I know `mechanize` supports relative URL's.

If javascript's a must, then I would suggest [firewatir](http://code.google.com/p/firewatir/). It can automate firefox, and this way you get a free javascript interpreter.

Comment: but what if redirection is conditional?